# Why the same change set can not be uploaded to 2 sandboxes simultaneously?

Tags: change-set

When uploading to one of the sandboxes is in progress and you try to deploy the same change set to another sandbox salesforce after abnormal long loading of page returns internal server error.

Why do they block parallel uploading of changeset to multiple sandboxes?

Comment: Even if you're cloning it ?

Comment: @FabienHuot Cloning helps to avoid the issue but technically it is 2 different changesets (even if they have the same list of components)

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an Internal Server Error, they're not "blocking" anything--there's a bug of some sort in the platform. That's what Internal Server Error means. You should report this error (including the Error ID) to Salesforce so salesforce.com can triage the situation. I'm not aware of any reason why this shouldn't be allowed, and I'm pretty sure it used to work correctly in the past.

Comment: Usually it takes ages to get tier 3 which can solve or confirm an issue. Stackexchange works faster )  But I will try and get back with their response